# How to implement shallow delete in Django

Tags: python, django

I really like the concept of shallow delete - when you delete a record it only sets it's deleted field to true but stays in a database. To remove it from the database, you have to delete it "forcefully", e.g. by setting some flag to true. The app then should always filter the deleted records, so they won't appear anywhere and they just seem like they are not in the db.

This is what I came up with and works pretty well.

```
class BaseManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(deleted=1)
        return qs

    def all_objects(self):
        return super().get_queryset()

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    deleted = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...

    objects = BaseManager()
    def delete(self, from_db=False, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        if from_db:
            super(BaseModel, self).delete(using, keep_parents)
            return
        self.deleted = 1
        self.save()
```

The problem is, that I have no idea, how to filter it on other places, let's say on related collections, many to many relationships or in queries, when the model is used for condition, foreign keys and who knows where else.

E.g. I have device called "Car" related to User. `User.objects.get(device__name="Car")` would return that user. When I shallowly delete the device (aka set deleted = true) and try to filter `User.objects.get(device__name="Car")`, I would like to get an empty result.

Another thing is that when a model has a foreign key, and the related model is shallowly deleted, the foreign key should be None.

Basically what I need is to somehow add `where x.deleted = 0` for every model (x) which appears in the query.

Is something like this even possible in Django?

Comment: You can override `_base_manager`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#base-managers although I do not know if that is advisable.

Comment: Could this perhaps be what you're looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects